# Excluding Selenium-server URL in JMeter Proxy Server

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, jmeter

I'm currently trying to get JMeter to record the steps my selenium tests so I can perform load testing with the same tests. The steps are recorded fine but my problem is that its also recording the steps performed in the "selenium-server" window (i.e. the extra windows that pop up when selenium runs).

I believe if I add something like `*selenium-server*` to the "URL Patterns to Exclude" List then it will ignore all these steps but they keep recording for every pattern I've tried.

Can someone please tell me the pattern which will lead to these steps getting ignore?
An example url is: `/selenium-server/driver/?retry=true`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following to 'URL Patterns to Exclude'

```
^/selenium-server/.*
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to use your Selenium tests to generate load, you might also want to look at [BrowserMob](http://browsermob.com). It's a company I started that runs actual Selenium browsers en masse in the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to add the following to 'URL Patterns to Exclude'

```
.*/selenium-server/.*
```